# Sending wchar_t message through serial port

Tags: c++, serial-port, putty

the problem that I have is that when sending a message L"Second line" to my application to read serial port I am receiving "S e c o n d  L i n e", but at putty I do received "Second line" I think that is because wchar_t is coded in 16 bit so I have a 00 between every letter. But still don't know how I can fix this, I am new with all these things so it is kind of confusing.

I am not sure if I need to set my byte size to 16 in my application?

I want to send that LPCWSTR LogpszMessage, because I am sending some logs messages from an application. Which is another code, working here must work there.

putty configuration is to 8 bits and this is what I am sending;

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef _Null_terminated_ CONST WCHAR *LPCWSTR, *PCWSTR;

int main()
{

    LPCWSTR LogpszMessage = L"Second line";
    char bytes_to_send[] = "test1 y test2";

    // Declare variables and structures
    HANDLE hSerial;
    DCB dcbSerialParams = { 0 };
    COMMTIMEOUTS timeouts = { 0 };

    // Open the highest available serial port number
    fprintf(stderr, "Opening serial port...");
    hSerial = CreateFile(
        L"\\\\.\\COM24", GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL,
        OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
    if (hSerial == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error\n");
        return 1;
    }
    else fprintf(stderr, "OK\n");

    dcbSerialParams.DCBlength = sizeof(dcbSerialParams);
    if (GetCommState(hSerial, &dcbSerialParams) == 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error getting device state\n");
        CloseHandle(hSerial);
        return 1;
    }

    dcbSerialParams.BaudRate = CBR_115200;
    dcbSerialParams.ByteSize = 8;
    dcbSerialParams.StopBits = ONESTOPBIT;
    dcbSerialParams.Parity = NOPARITY;
    if (SetCommState(hSerial, &dcbSerialParams) == 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error setting device parameters\n");
        CloseHandle(hSerial);
        return 1;
    }

    // Set COM port timeout settings
    timeouts.ReadIntervalTimeout = 50;
    timeouts.ReadTotalTimeoutConstant = 50;
    timeouts.ReadTotalTimeoutMultiplier = 10;
    timeouts.WriteTotalTimeoutConstant = 50;
    timeouts.WriteTotalTimeoutMultiplier = 10;
    if (SetCommTimeouts(hSerial, &timeouts) == 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error setting timeouts\n");
        CloseHandle(hSerial);
        return 1;
    }

    // Send specified text (remaining command line arguments)
    DWORD bytes_written, total_bytes_written = 0;
    fprintf(stderr, "Sending bytes...");
    /*if (!WriteFile(hSerial, bytes_to_send, sizeof(bytes_to_send), &bytes_written, NULL))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error\n");
        CloseHandle(hSerial);
        return 1;
    }*/

    if (!WriteFile(hSerial, LogpszMessage, wcslen(LogpszMessage) * sizeof(wchar_t), &bytes_written, NULL))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error\n");
        CloseHandle(hSerial);
        return 1;
    }
    fprintf(stderr, "%d bytes written\n", bytes_written);

    // Close serial port
    fprintf(stderr, "Closing serial port...");
    if (CloseHandle(hSerial) == 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error\n");
        return 1;
    }
    fprintf(stderr, "OK\n");
    getchar();

    // exit normally
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Putty simply prints the displayable text for the bytes it receives and has no idea whatsoever that you are sending utf16.  A binary zero is special, there is no equivalent character for it.  So you simply can't see it and it merely *looks* like it is working correctly.  Check [this superuser.com question](https://superuser.com/questions/150202/display-hex-in-putty-for-serial).  If you don't want those binary zeros to appear in the log file then you need to get ahead by choosing an encoding for the text you transmit.  Consider WideCharToMultiByte() with CP_ACP or CP_UTF8.

Comment: Thank you @HansPassantM let me read about WideCharToMultiByte() and try it. I completely understand your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I could not do it with WideCharToMultiByte(), yield me error when trying to use LPCWSTR LogpszMessage, so I did the job with [wcstombs_s](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s7wzt4be.aspx) following microsoft documentation and it worked, now when reading the COM port there is no spaces caused by 00 of 16 bit characters.

Thank you [Hans Passant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17034/hans-passant)!